# Word meaning "the state of having (specific) metrics"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means an object is in such a state that it has specific metrics able to be associated with it. I'm thinking "metered" but I'm not sure if that is necessarily appropriate as the dictionary definitions for "metered" point to measuring using the metric system, traffic meters, or metering the distribution of something in distinct units.

The use case is that at a certain state of being, an object has specific data associated with it (performance metrics), but it would not have this data in some other state. So when it is in the state that has the data, what word would I use to describe this? I'm looking for a generic word as well, not being directly related to the state itself, as the object could satisfy this condition in multiple different states (the inverse also being true: the object could not satisfy this condition in multiple different states).

Sometimes naming things is the hardest part of programming.

Comment: Are you looking for "***measurable***"? Your term "***metered***", which not only implies "*measurable*", but also "*actively monitored*" or "*in a state of being measured*" is also perfectly fine and apt.

Comment: The idea of "in a state of being measured" is exactly what I'm looking for. I was just unsure of the validity of using "metered" to represent this, as well as looking for a better alternative if there is one.

Comment: Probably 'computable' : determined  by mathematics, especially by numerical methods.

Comment: "instrumented" is commonly used for this state in programming, but usually there's the implication that this is something applied externally to the subject (ie that *instruments* have been applied). Your, more general request, presumably covers the case where things spring into a measurable state due to internal change.

Comment: @DanSheppard That is accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "***metered***" is perfectly appropriate, valid, and well attested in this context (ever take a cab where the ride was *metered*?).

Answer (score 3):

As @Dan Bron says, *[measurable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/measurable)* seems to fit your criterion

> Able to be measured:
>   *objectives should be measurable and achievable* [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

An alternative, albeit much less common, is *[mensurable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mensurable)*

> capable of being measured :  measurable [*Merriam-Webster*]

Comment: I'd also recommend adding "***metered***" to your answer. The OP worried that it's invalid, but it's not, so "***metered***" is probably the answer he's looking for (in other words, it would earn you a ✓).

Comment: It would indeed. I'm sticking with metered.

Comment: @DanBron Your answers. Add and be selected.